# Como criar um servidor Git na rede interna?

Tags: git

Tem como criar um servidor local Git?

Não gostaria de ficar dependente da internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tem sim! Tem [um capítulo](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) no livro Pro Git que cobre isso. O livro está disponível online.

Recomendo a leitura porque há várias opções. Você pode, por exemplo, precisar de autenticação para acesso de leitura ou pode exigir mais velocidade do servidor. Para cada uma dessas escolhas, há um protocolo recomendado. O Github, por exemplo, provê acesso de leitura para os repositórios públicos via protocolo git (mais leve e rápido). Mas para acesso de escrita dos commiters do projeto, usa SSH (um pouco mais pesado, mas provê autenticação). Outra opção é HTTP para leitura, que facilita atravessar firewalls corporativas.

Enfim, há basicamente quatro opções:

- Mapeamento local
- SSH
- Protocolo próprio do git
- HTTP

O que você vai escolher (ou se vai optar por uma solução híbrida, como o Github) depende das suas necessidades. Por isso recomendo a leitura do livro.

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta?

Comment: elaborado! lembrando que a solução de mapeamento local (que parece ser o que as demais respostas estão sugerindo até agora) nem sempre é aplicável a todas as situações.

Answer (score 3):

Para você iniciar um repositório GIT em qualquer lugar, basta digitar:

```
git init
```

Se a pasta onde esse repositório está for acessível local, usb, ou rede, ele passa você vai poder dar push pra ele, colocando em seu outro repositório como remote.

Por exemplo, eu tenho na minha pasta de projetos e no meu USB o mesmo repositório:

```
/home/gartz/projects/foo
$ git init
```

E também no meu USB:

```
/media/usb_gartz/foo
$ git init
```

Agora basta cadastrar no meu projeto pessoal o usb como remoto e ele vai ser meu servidor de GIT `/home/gartz/projects/foo`

```
$ git remote add origin /media/usb_gartz/foo
```

Agora sempre que eu der um push ou fetch ele vai buscar na origin que no caso é o `/media/usb_gartz/foo` e é local.

Você pode adicionar o acesso via qualquer protocolo, SSH, SMB, FTP, etc se quiser dar acesso remoto ao seu servidor.

Mas se você não quiser um snapshot do seu projeto no seu servidor local, pode usar o bare repository que nada mais é que a pasta `.git` que é criada, você pode copiar ela e apontar pra ela, igual no exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando ao que o Gabriel Gartz disse: o Git não possui um servidor centralizado. O Git, assim como o Mercurial por exemplo, é um repositório não centralizado. Você não cria um servidor Git, mas um repositório master - que pode ser qualquer repositório git da sua rede.

Para tal, basta você escolher qual máquina da sua rede será o repositório "canonical"/"master", configurar seu IP/nome corretamente, e configurar as outras máquinas para fazerem push para ele (ou seja, ele seria o Master) como você faria com o Bitbucket/Github. Os processos de versionamento não mudarão.

Answer (score 1):

Podes preparar o teu proprio servidor git usando o [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/community/) ou o [Gitorious](http://getgitorious.com/).

Answer (score 1):

No seu servidor você cria o diretório git fazendo:

```
git init --bare
```

Na estação onde você vai trabalhar você inicializa apenas com

```
git init
```

Bem veja mais num artigo que escrevi em 2011 apesar de antigo os códigos permanecem os mesmos: http://oraculum.blog.br/blogoraculum/index.php/git-comandos-basicos/

Answer (score 0):

Diferente de soluções como cvs e svn o Git é descentralizado. Você não precisa ter um servidor fixo. Você pode simplesmente compartilhar uma pasta na rede e fazer `push` para lá. Pode também colocar um servidor ssh na sua rede interna.